# Finding function formula

Tags: functions

So, I have this function: $$f(\frac{k+1}{2})=k+(\frac{k+1}{2})^2$$
I need to find an expression for $f(k)$. How to do that, for this example and in general? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $x=\frac{k+1}{2}$, solve for $k$, and substitute.  $f(x)=x^2+2x-1$.

Comment: ohhhhh ty sir, that was kinda obvious but i was stuck. ty!

Comment: Michael Burr's answer points to a generalized method for doing this. Setting $x=\frac{k+1}{2}$ gives you the form you're looking for, namely $f(k)$. From there you just need to change RHS to be in terms of $x$

Answer (score 2):

> $$f\left( \frac { k+1 }{ 2 }  \right) =2\cdot \frac { k+1 }{ 2 } -1+\left( \frac { k+1 }{ 2 }  \right) ^{ 2 }\\ f\left( x \right) =2x-1+{ x }^{ 2 }$$

Comment: The OP also asks how to do this problem in general.